# Cannot find DNX process after updating Visual Studio 2015 from Update1 to Update 3

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I have a .net solution that was built using VS2015 Update 1 IDE.  It's an ASP.net solution, hosting two web projects.

I installed the latest update 3 to visual studio 2015 and now I'm getting the error "**An error occurred while attempting to determine the process id of the DNX process hosting your application**" while attempting to run my web project.

[image]

I had previously configured my app url to have https in it.  I've noticed that reverting it to an http address allows the website to kick off but I need it to be https.

How can I fix this?

NOTE: Visual studio version
[image]

Comment: Are you meaning Visual Studio 15 Preview 3? (not to be confused with vs2015 that has been released for some time now)

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't clear with my information - I had Update 1 and installed update 3 (version info shown above now).  That's when the problem happened.Thx

Answer (score -1):

From your screen shots, your using ASP.NET Core RC1 which uses DNX. ASP.NET Core 1.0 uses ***dotnet*** instead of DNX or DNVM.

Now after updating to VS 2015 Update 3, you should be migrating to ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM which will solve you issue.

It's merely modifying some JSON files, your source code won't be affected. Refer this http://www.talkingdotnet.com/quick-migration-guide-asp-net-core-rtm-rc2/

Comment: He is using a pre-RC2 version of ASP.NET Core.  The link you gave him is for migrating from RC2 to RTM.  Going from dnx to dotnet CLI is a big step and involves much more than modifying some JSON files.

Comment: I've basically worked around the issue by recreating my solution in the new version of .net and copying my code files in.  The majority of the code worked fine, new namespaces (generally replaceing .AspNet. with .AspNetCore. worked fine).  Startup.cs is the file that's changed the most for me.